# Asymptotic behavior of a truncated MGF of a quadratic form of a standard gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics

Assume $X$ follows an $n$ dimensional standard Gaussian distribution and $A$ is an $n\times n$ semi-definite matrix. I am trying to analyze the asymptotic behavior of $\mathbb{E} e^{-X^TAX} \mathbf{1}_{X^TAX \geq n}$ as $n\to +\infty$. By spectral decompositon, we only need to consider the case when $A$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries.

For the special case when $A = \mathbf{I}_n$, I think we can deal with it by Laplace's Method. What I got is

\begin{align}
& \mathbb{E} e^{-X^T\mathbf{I}_nX} \mathbf{1}_{X^T\mathbf{I}_nX \geq n}\\
& = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\int_{n}^{+\infty} x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{3}{2}x}dx\\
& = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}n^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \int_1^{+\infty} y^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{3}{2}y}dy \quad(y = \frac{x}{n})\\
&\sim \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}n^{\frac{n}{2}-1}  \frac{1}{n e^{\frac{3}{2}n}}\quad (\text{by Laplace's Method})
\end{align}

But for general $A = diag\{\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n\}$ (and $\lambda_i$ may depend on $n$), there is no closed-form pdf for the distribution $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i X_i^2$. So I don't know how to proceed.

Are there some methods/techniques that can be applied to this case?

Comment: Your matrix $A$ (and even the set of its eigenvalues) necessarily depend on $n$. The asymptotics in question will depend on that dependence.